# My variable is coming up as not defined, when I think I have defined it

Tags: python

This is my code

```
#project starts here
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import pi
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def deriv(cond,t):
    for q in range (0,N):
        i=6*q
        dydt[i]=cond[i+3]
        dydt[i+1]=cond[i+4]
        dydt[i+2]=cond[i+5]
        r=sqrt((cond[i])**2 +(cond[i+1])**2 +(cond[i+2])**2)
        dydt[i+3]=-G*M*cond[i]/(r**3)
        dydt[i+4]=-G*M*cond[i+1]/(r**3)
        dydt[i+5]=-G*M*cond[i+2]/(r**3)
    return dydt

G=1
M=1
N=12
vmag=((G*M)/(2))**(0.5)
theta = np.linspace(0,2*pi,N)
x=2*np.cos(theta)
y=2*np.sin(theta)
vx=-vmag*np.sin(theta)
vy=vmag*np.cos(theta)
z=np.zeros(N)
vz=np.zeros(N)
t=np.linspace(0,30,100)

cond=list(item for group in zip(x,y,z,vx,vy,vz) for item in group)
sln=odeint(deriv, cond, t, args=(G,M))
```

I am getting an error message about dydt not being defined. I thought I had defined it within my derivatives function. My intention is for it to be a vector with the appropriate derivatives in it (hence the use of i) of the cond array. Why is my definition wrong?

Comment: Well, you clearly didn't define it. You have to assign something to `dydt` like `dydt = ...`

Comment: dydt is only accessed by index. It is never assigned as a list of the necessary size

Comment: But I want to define it based on the cond array which I define further down. Should I define it as a vector of zeros and then allow it to be modified? Using append or something?

Answer (score 0):

"dydt" is not defined, you should define it before you can use indexes on it.

Regarding your code, you could do something like this:

```
i = 6*q
dydt = list(range(i))
```

Comment: I then get the error "TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment". Any idea why?

Comment: Ah thank you, that appears to have worked. However (I know this isn't 100% a followup to the same question), I then get the error "IndexError: list assignment index out of range". Is this range the one I have defined in my for statement, or is this to do with the way I have defined dydt?

Comment: @TimSmith This is probably because you are going somewhere not defined in the list, I see you are accessing i (maximum in your list) + X, which is not possible in your case. You should size correctly your list before trying to access indexes.

Comment: I'm trying to make it so the first element of dydt is the 4th element of cond, the 7th of dydt is the 10th element of cond, etc. Is using i not the way to select the appropriate parts of the list?